# Error while assigning function to the values of a dictionary

Tags: string, python-3.x, function, dictionary, text

I am trying to assign a function to the values of my dict with with the below command:

```
x_text = [clean_str(v) for k, v in answer.items()]
```

Function clean_str:

```
def clean_str(string):
    # remove stopwords
    # string = ' '.join([word for word in string.split() if word not in cachedStopWords])
    string = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9(),!?\'\`]", " ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'s", " \'s", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'ve", " \'ve", string)
    string = re.sub(r"n\'t", " n\'t", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'re", " \'re", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'d", " \'d", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'ll", " \'ll", string)
    string = re.sub(r",", " , ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"!", " ! ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\(", " \( ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\)", " \) ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\?", " \? ", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", string)
    return string.strip().lower()
```

But i am getting the below error:

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

A snippet of first 2 k,v pairs of my dict(answer{}) is below:

```
In[45]:{k: answer[k] for k in list(answer)[:2]}
Out[45]: 
{b'B00308CJ12': [b'Bulletproof Salesman (2008)'],
 b'189138922X': [b'Classical Mechanics']}
```

Comment: Please show the code of `clean_str()`.

Comment: Edited original qn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of your dict are all bytes rather than strings, and `re.sub` can only process strings.

You should convert the bytes to strings with the `decode()` method:

```
x_text = [clean_str(i.decode()) for k, v in answer.items() for i in v]
```

Comment: >>error:'list' object has no attribute 'decode'<<I guess because the values are a list. Is there a way of converting the values from list to normal string sentence?

Comment: I see. Not sure why your value is a list if it only has one item, but you can always use another for loop in the list comprehension to extract the values within. I've updated my answer accordingly then.